# Table formatting ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Quick ASP.NET question:    I am able to change width on this line: `<table class="style1" width="100%" >` (and I actually get the autocompletion facility when typing width).
However, when I try to set the width of the columns: `<td width="10%">` I don't get autocomplete for width; setting the width for "td" doesn't reflect at all when running the project. Why?

This is how it starts:

```
<table class="style1" width="100%" >
<tr>
<td width="33%">
...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
<td style="width:10%" ></td>
```

Comment: You're not quite on the money with not being able to use % with width. You can do this, the w3Schools reference shows it explicitly. You're correct about using styles instead though.

Answer (score 1):

TD isn't a column, it is a cell, try col and colgroup instead ([see the documentation here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_col.asp)). However... This style of layout is frowned upon now. Try using CSS based layout instead, it'll make your life a happier place.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I have TR = row and TD = cells, for a row I set three 3 cells, so I want each to be 33% in width. I don't see why it's not working.

Comment: The width attribute is deprecated for TD, TD is a cell, not a column. Try a colgroup or CSS styles instead. If you're still stuck, post all of your markup and I'm sure I can help.

Comment: Many thanks, I used colgroup as described in your documentation and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @AnnaT Awesome! Glad to have helped :)